# Rails Bundle - one gem two versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have old rails application. And this application need the same gem with different versions.

For example, it use now

gem 'actionmailer' 2.3.5 and 'actionmailer' 2.3.2 
gem 'actionpack', '2.3.5' and 'actionpack', '2.3.2'

Dont ask me why =) This is old app and very massive. Current rails version 2.3.5

Now i try to use bundler for my gems control. But Bundler can`t allows use one gem twice in config. Or i can see error like this:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":   In
>   Gemfile:
>       datanoise-actionwebservice (= 2.3.2) ruby depends on
>         actionpack (= 2.3.2) ruby
>
> ```
> rails (= 2.3.5) ruby depends on
>   actionpack (2.3.5)
> ```

So, can i solve this problem or not and i can`t use Bundler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datanoise-actionwebservice seems to be very (probably too) restrictive about actionpack and activerecord versions in it's gemspec. However I see that internally it tries to load these gems with '>= 2.3.0' versions (see lib/action_web_service.rb).

I'd suggest trying forking this gem and patching it's gemspec, so the version requirements for actionpack and activerecord are changed to '>= 2.3.2'.

Then update your project's Gemfile to use the patched version:

```
gem 'datanoise-actionwebservice', :git => "http://github.com/youraccount/actionwebservice.git"
```

Hopefully it will work with 2.3.5 as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, you must either upgrade your `datanoise-actionwebservice` to version 2.3.5, or downgrade your `rails` to 2.3.2.

I suggest upgrading the `datanoise-actionwebservice` if possible.

Comment: Too bad :( There is no 'datanoise-actionwebservice' with version 2.3.5. Downgrade my app for 2.3.2 not good for me also. So... i think... there is no more options?

Comment: It is not possible :( Version for 2.3.5 not exist